# Log Database Actions Using a Decorator Pattern

Tags: java

For a lab in one of my classes I have been given the task to add logging functionality to a database using the decorator pattern. The spot I am currently stuck on is trying to create a log that is different for each method called. For example, there is a method that will join two tables in the database and I would like the log to say "Join Table1 and Table2" as well as having the ability to be wrapped with something like a time stamp from a different logger. I was wondering how I should go about writing the concrete decorators so there won't be a separate logging method for each method the database uses.

This is what I have for the general logger right now.

```
public abstract class Logger extends DB implements DataBase {
DataBase db;
ArrayList<String> log = new ArrayList<String>();
public Logger(DataBase db){
    this.db = db;
}
public DBTable getTable(String name){
    logAction("Get Table ");
    return db.getTable(name);
}
public void createTable(String name, int columns){
    logAction("Create Table "+name+" ");
    db.createTable(name, columns);
}
public void insert(String tableName, String[] row){
    logAction("Insert "+tableName+" ");
    db.insert(tableName, row);
}
public DBTable select(String tabName, int col, String selector){
    logAction("Select "+tabName+" ");
    return db.select(tabName, col, selector);
}
public DBTable join(String tab1Name, String tab2Name, int tab1Col, int tab2Col){
    logAction("Join "+tab1Name+" and "+tab2Name+" ");
    return db.join(tab1Name, tab2Name, tab1Col, tab2Col);
}
public void logAction(String logInfo){
    log.add(logInfo);
}
```

}

DB is the actual database, while DataBase is the interface that is implemented by everything.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "there won't be a separate logging method for each method the database uses"? Do you mean you don't want separate calls for each method or are you planning to write a log method for each individual method?

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to have a specific message for each log entry along with default data. Since each message can be represented as a series of printable characters, we can just make it the argument to a `log()` function, like the below:

```
public void log(String msg) {
    String timestamp = getTimestamp(); //Or however you get the time
    String logThis = timestamp + " " + msg + "\n";
    //Log logThis...
}
```

This way you could just call the log with the specific message (e.g. "Joined Tables 1 and 2") and the default parameters would be added every time. If you're comfortable with reflection, this would also be a great chance to practice writing [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) that could automatically do the logging for you.

Comment: I still dont have that great of understanding of the entire pattern, but how would I be able to extend this class in order to wrap it with more descriptive loggers?

Comment: If you implement it the way I suggest, in later classes you could extend the current class and override the `log()` method so it would be more descriptive than the current one.

Comment: The part that I'm not understanding is that if you simply override the method, how can you add multiple decorators that each add to the comment that will be logged? Thank you for the help, by the way

Comment: By using the super() call, you can use the parent's class logging functionality and then add on to it. In this instance you could call super() and get the default information logged, then use custom logic afterwards to log your more specific message. **TL;DR** Inheritance

Comment: I see what you're saying now. It took a little while to click. Thank you.